# Count the number of records in group_by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, group-by

I have the following categories grouped together:

```
@categories = Category.all.group_by { |c| c.name }
```

In my view I am displaying the category names like so:

```
<% @categories.each do |c, v| %>
  <li><%= link_to c, blog_path(:name => c) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Which gives this for example:

```
Ruby
Ruby On Rails
CSS
```

What I want to achieve is next to each category name have the total number of posts with that category name, so:

```
Ruby(2)
Ruby On Rails(10)
```

So I have tried:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:posts).all.group_by { |c| c.name }
```

Which results in only the categories with a post object being displayed (previously all categories would display, regardless of whether they had a post object) and in my view I tried:

```
<% @categories.each do |c, v| %>
  <li><%= link_to c, blog_path(:name => c) %><%= c.count %></li>
<% end %>
```

This is outputting nothing. I'd like to find how to approach this before I confuse the matter.

Comment: try `.includes` instead of `.joins` - does that make any difference?

Comment: .includes now shows all the categories again, but still no output on the count

Comment: why are you grouping by name?

Comment: @MikeCampbell what else would i group by? I want to list all the category names so that as user can click on one and then see all posts belonging to that category

Comment: why do you have multiple categories with the same name?

Comment: @MikeCampbell I dont...each category is only listed once

Comment: so why do you need to group? _baffled_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's confusing to call the grouped categories @categories because that makes it sound like a collection of Category objects, when it's actually a Hash.  Using descriptive names, including in your loop, makes your code much clearer.

Try this:

```
@category_groups = Category.includes(:posts).all.group_by { |c| c.name }
```

and the view

```
<% @category_groups.each do |name, categories| %>
  <li><%= link_to name, blog_path(:name => name) %> (<%= categories.map{|category| category.posts.size}.sum %> posts)</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes your right, i should use better naming conventions, thanks for the tip.. Also your answer works...thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using `group_by`. However, you don't need a join because you don't have any condition on `posts`. Other examples suggest eager loading posts, but that seems overkill to initialise all the post objects in memory to just get the count of them. You'd need to do your own benchmarks though. Consider a counter_cache like another answerer suggested.

```
@categories = Category.all
```

and in the view:

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= link_to c.name, blog_path(:name => c.name) %> (<%= c.posts.count %> posts)</li>
<% end %>
```

**Further explanation**

[`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) returns a hash with the key as the unique return value from the block, and the value are all items of the original array for which the block evaluates to that key. Taking your example of `Category.all` (the scope is converted to an array before `group_by` so that's how we'll represent it here):

```
cats = [
         #<Category name: "foo" ... >,
         #<Category name: "bar" ... >,
         #<Category name: "baz" ... >
       ]
```

These three categories have unique names, so using `.group_by { |c| c.name }` does nothing but create a pointless hash with the keys as the name, and each value as an array with one Category object like:

```
{
  "foo" => [#<Category name: "foo" ... >],
  "bar" => [#<Category name: "bar" ... >],
  "baz" => [#<Category name: "baz" ... >]
}
```

Here's an example of where you might use `group_by` to some effect:

```
languages = ["Ada", "C++", "CLU", "Eiffel", "Lua", "Lisp",
             "Perl", "Python", "Smalltalk"]
languages_grouped_by_first_letter = languages.group_by { |s| s[0] }     
=> {"A"=>["Ada"], "C"=>["C++", "CLU"], "E"=>["Eiffel"], "L"=>["Lua", "Lisp"], "P"=>["Perl", "Python"], "S"=>["Smalltalk"]}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will look into benchmarks and record the differences between using group_by and not using it. thanks again for the tip

Comment: the `group_by` is entirely superfluous in your case, regardless of whether you decide to eager load or not, so it WILL add overhead.

Comment: would you mind giving an example of when i would use group_by then within your answer please? just trying to understand why i dont need it, the code you have provided works but looking to understand the difference between the two, thank you

Comment: thank you for expanding the answer, I can see where your confusion was coming from and i can now see why it was unnecessary to use group_by

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code

```
@categories = Category.all.group_by { |c| c.name }
```

Write a Hepler to find post_count

```
def post_count(category_ids)
  Post.where(:category_id => category_ids)
end
```

In View:

```
<% @categories.each do |c, v| %>
  <li><%= link_to c, blog_path(:name => c) %>(<%= post_count(v.map(&:id)) %>)</li>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That will show the number of categories in each group.  He wants the number of **posts** for each category.

Comment: @MaxWilliams My BAD!! :( Modified the answer. Hope this helps now!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `counter_cache`.

In our `Post` model,set `counter_cahe => true`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to category,:counter_cache => true

end
```

Add `posts_count` column to `categories` table and do like this

```
@category_groups = Category.find(:all)

<% @category_groups.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= link_to name, blog_path(:name => c) %>(<%= posts_count)</li>
<% end %>
```

Look this **[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)** For implementing this.